# What do you call adding zeros to a table of frequency counts of consecutive integers where the given integer does not occur

Tags: data-transformation, tables, presentation

I am wondering what the proper term is, for when a table like this (where values that did not occur are omitted entirely):

```
 ________ _______
| Length | Count |
|--------|-------|
|      1 |     5 |
|      3 |     2 |
|      6 |    12 |
|________|_______|
```

Is rewritten like this (where values that did not occur are noted with a frequency of zero):

```
 ________ _______
| Length | Count |
|      1 |     5 |
|      2 |     0 |
|      3 |     2 |
|      4 |     0 |
|      5 |     0 |
|      6 |    12 |
|________|_______|
```

Comment: If it's truly missing data, I would call it a (bad) form of single imputation. If the missing rows truly mean that the count was zero (i.e. there is no uncertainty involved), I do not know of a name. But then I wonder if it needs one, because it's only a step 'behind the scenes' (data cleansing)

Comment: I am trying to extract data via SQL for a Histogram, so if there is no row it means 0.
Isn't this something like normalizing?

Comment: IF you're trying to create a histogram, you shouldn't need the zeroes. What software are you using?

Comment: well it is not missing, there just no observations for 2, 4, 5, so you could just right 0 for not observed (it is truly different from missing) data. However to make nice histograms, I think, you have to group the intervals to include at least 5 counts in it. So for example 1-3 4-6 would be one of possible devisions.

Comment: @Tie-figher I tried to come up with a clearer title given that the data isn't "missing" in the statistical sense. feel free to modify.

Comment: I second @Nick Sabbe; if the missing rows are in fact observed zeros then all you're doing is recoding your data (and it shouldn't be necessary in order to calculate a histogram). You also observed 0 for the integers in 6-infinity but it would be inconvenient to include 0's those in your dataset ;)

Comment: Is it fair to say that the unobserved integers exist in the population but not in the finite data sample?

Comment: I'd see this just as a way of making explicit in a report what is implicit in the data, namely that certain values that might have occurred did not occur in the dataset to hand. It's nothing to do with imputation.. It is common with one-way tables in many fields to fill gaps with zero counts, and very common with two-way or higher tables to show zeros when combinations of categories do not occur (you could hardly do otherwise).

Comment: It's a matter of taste and circumstance when to do it. For example, if I had family sizes 1 to 7 and 17 I would probably not have rows showing zero counts for sizes 8 to 16, but it would not be crazy to do that, just not usually a good use of reporting space. As to the question, I don't know a special name for this and I don't think a name is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping a set of observed value onto the observable values expected for a given variable?

That is, a variable is characterized by all hypothetical values that can be observed when using it, but observed values may not reflect the full range of possible values. For example, when collecting n=100 discrete scores on a 0-20 point scale, you might end up with some scores that were observed more often than other, while some never occurred.

And if the number of observable (distinct) value is so small, I would suggest some kind of bar graph (or a dot chart) rather than an histogram, which for a random sample might look like this:

[image]

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do in Excel :/
What's the difference between a bargraph and a histogram?

Comment: @Tie-fighter A barplot is for discrete outcomes, an histogram is for continuous ones (that will be grouped into contiguous bins).

Comment: Late comment, but I am happy to regard **bar chart** as a general **graphical** term for any chart with bars, including histograms as a special case; and **histogram** as a specifically **statistical** term for a representation of a frequency distribution using bars; the bars should touch when the variable is continuous and binned; but the bars may be separate when the variable is discrete. So my senses are broader than those given above.

Comment: @Nick Others make a different distinction: a bar chart represents quantities by means of the *lengths* of the bars whereas a histogram represents quantities by means of the *areas* of the bars. This distinction acquires some force when you contemplate (a) interpreting variable-width histograms or (b) what happens as the amount of data increases and the bar widths decrease (the data histogram approaches a probability density function, if one exists). The area interpretation does not preclude using histograms to represent discrete data, but (b) explains chl's reference to continuous variables.

Comment: @whuber Naturally I agree. I didn't and wouldn't define a histogram as requiring bars of equal width. I've seen bar charts with unequal widths that weren't histograms. Most importantly,  emphasis on area as a key principle would be essential  in a fuller, self-contained explanation.